# Return Observable of arrays from rxjs/Subject (Observable.from vs. Observable.of)

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I am using WebSockets to communicate with backend WebApi. Everything is working fine, EXCEPT I cannot return my custom object from my service.

I am using Angular 4.3.4 and rxjs 5.4.3.

```
//ngInit from my component
ngOnInit() {
    this.modelsSubscription = this.mainService.getModels().subscribe(models => {
      this.models = models;
    });

//here's code from my service
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

import { WebsocketService } from './websocket.service';
import { MyModel} from '../models/my-Model';
import { ApplicationError } from '../globals/application-error';


@Injectable()
export class MainService {
  messages$: Observable<MyModel[]>;

  private messages: Subject<MyModel[]>;
  private webApiUrl: string;
  private wsApiUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private wsService: WebsocketService) {
    this.webApiUrl = environment.webApiUrl + '/api/mainscreen/';
    this.wsApiUrl = this.webApiUrl.replace('http:', 'ws:');
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.wsService.disconnect();
  }

  getModels() {
    this.messages = <Subject<MyModel[]>>this.wsService
      .connect(`${this.wsApiUrl}GetModels`)
      .map((response: MessageEvent): Observable<MyModel[]> => {
        const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        const myModels = MyModel.fromArray(data);
        // return Observable.from(myModels) // <-- throws error Type 'Observable<MyModel>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MyModel[]>'
         // return myModels; // <-- throws error myModels[] is not assignable to Observable<myModels[]>
        return new Observable<MyModels[]>(observer => {
          observer.next(myModels); // <-- never gets called
          observer.complete();
        });
      })
      .catch((error: any) =>
        Observable.throw(new ApplicationError(error))
      );

    this.messages$ = this.messages.asObservable();
    return this.messages$;
  }    
}
```

How can I return Observable from service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you would provide a plunker. So far I think that you are confusing `Observable.from` and `Observable.of`:

**Observable.from**

This operator is iterating over your array elements and push those to the Observable. That's why you got type compatibility issue:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html

**Observable.of**

This operator creates Observable from params passed to it: 
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of

**Summarizing. You should change:**

```
return Observable.from(myModels)
```

to:

```
return Observable.of(myModels)
```

**Example:**

```
var myModels = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
Observable.from(myModels).subscribe(value => console.log("value is: " + value));
Observable.of(myModels).subscribe(value => console.log("value is: " + value));
```

Output will be:

```
value is: a
value is: b
value is: c
value is: d
value is: [a, b, c, d]
```

Comment: You were correct using Observable.of resolved my issue. However, now the subscribe method in ngOninit on the component returns ScalarObservable. Do you know how I can import ScalarObservable?